# Plotting dates with timezones in matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

How do I properly set pyplot to plot dates in a given timezone?
I can see various places to put a tzinfo object, but all of these either do nothing or do not remotely work as expected.  I load a list of records from a csv, with each record being [naive timestamp in UTC, number to plot]

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
estZone=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')

records=[['10/10/17 12:00','100'],['11/10/17 12:00','150'],['12/10/17 12:00','200']]

def parseDT(stampString):
    return datetime.strptime(stampString,'%d/%m/%y %H:%M')

def plotGraph():
    xvalues=[]
    yvalues=[]
    for r in records:
        rdatetime=(parseDT(r[0])) #parseDT just returns naive DT
        rdatetime=pytz.utc.localize(rdatetime)
        rdatetime=rdatetime.astimezone(tz=estZone)
        xvalues.append(rdatetime)
        yvalues.append(int(r[1]))

    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))
    plt.plot_date(xvalues,yvalues,ls='solid',lw=1.5,aa=True,marker='None',color='g')
    dayFmt=mdates.DateFormatter('%a-%b-%d')
    hrFmt=mdates.DateFormatter('%H:00')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dayFmt)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.HourLocator(byhour=[6,12,18]))
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(hrFmt)
    plt.grid(b=True, which='both',linestyle='dotted')
    plt.show()

plotGraph()
```

This produces (minus some formatting) this figure:

[image: First output]
Which is actually still UTC.  It's identical to the result if I had omitted the `astimezone(tz=estZone)`, even though I've verified that part is definitely functioning.

If I proceed to pass `tz=estZone` to `plt.plot_date`, the figure is identical.  There's no change. How can I change this to make an EST graph from my UTC timestamps?

Comment: You would want to provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to add that would make it more clear.  The code block contains everything relevant and nothing but.  It's plotting UTC.  I'd like it to plot times in EST.  Included are examples of things that do not work.

Comment: The main engine that drives any kind of debugging is reproducibility. Now I cannot reproduce the above issue, because no [mcve] is given. I.e. I cannot copy the code and run it to see the issue. Hence I cannot test certain things to locate the problem and thus I cannot help you. Of course you may be lucky and find the one guy that wrote the package pass by to know what's going on from the top of his head, or you may find someone with too much time writing such example himself. But most of the time, questions without [mcve] are simply closed as off-topic or will never get answered. Your choice.

Comment: Alright, it's runnable independantly now.

Answer (score 4):

I've been going through this for the past hour as well: the source data had the correct timezone, but Matplotlib was ignoring it. The fix is passing the timezone to the locators *and* formatters.

Example code to clarify:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=1, tz=local_tz))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%y', tz=local_tz))
```

Answer (score 1):

I had tried passing the timezone to the DateFormatters for the x-axis labels before, but the timezone modifier seems to be applied after the locators are placed, leaving all the labels reading 4 hours behind each midnight or the hours specified.  I've realized that the locators also need the timezone as a parameter to counteract this.  That'd do it.